# Json Parsing Exception when we convert in to Map

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

```
"{\"isDownloaded\":\"T\",\"comment\":\"{\\\"TAG\\\":\\\"Others\\\",\\\"COMMENT\\\":\\\"Re: Urgent Paytm gateway redirection issue\\\"}\",\"merchCommPref\":\"0\"}"
```

I want this json value to parse in `Map<String, String>` contains JSON value;

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

profile = mapper.readValue(doc, Map.class);
```

I am getting below exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)):
```

Comment: You are not showing the class you want to deserialize into.

Comment: I tested your code assuming that the `String doc = "{}"; // long JSON string`, `Map<String, String> profile = mapper.readValue(doc, Map.class);` and it worked fine.

Comment: @AlexRudenko doc value is "{\"isDownloaded\":\"T\",\"comment\":\"{\\\"TAG\\\":\\\"Others\\\",\\\"COMMENT\\\":\\\"Re: Urgent Paytm gateway redirection issue\\\"}\",\"merchCommPref\":\"0\"}"

Comment: @architkumar, I know that, I skipped it for brevity

Comment: works perfectly fine for me as well.

Comment: Are you sure that what you’ve shown is the exact string you’re trying to parse?  That string parses just fine for me.